# Нахождение подстроки регулярным выражением

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Есть длинная строка в 20000 знаков. В ней надо найти подстроку которая начинается на определенные 3 буквы и заканчивается на другие три буквы. Пробовал такое используя модуль re
`re.findall(r'ATG\w+TAA')` , выводит всю строку.

Comment: А если так `r'(ATG\w+TAA)'`?

Comment: Опять всю строку показывает

Comment: Всю строку в 20000 знаков или всю строку, начинающуюся с ATG и заканчивающуюся на TAA? Если нужна строка между теми подстроками, то `r'ATG(\w+)TAA'`

Comment: всю на 20000, так как в начале есть ATG и в конце TAA, но между ними встречается множество TAA, и он не выдает первое вхождение, а идет до самого конца

Comment: Если вы ищите кодирующие последовательности ДНК, то так: ATG[AGTC]+?TAA

Comment: Спасибо, вроде заработало

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

t = "dagehrgteshrtjTERHtnregATGfwaehrytewasehrT#D#AWTAAesrdj5hy$H$EWFEGRdwafsegdrhthrgefwATGwesrhtjrht34AWT#rtj6h5y4t34y5y4t3T$YRHGTR"

print(re.findall(r'ATG.*?AWT', t))
```

Вывод:

```
>> ['ATGfwaehrytewasehrT#D#AWT', 'ATGwesrhtjrht34AWT']
```

Comment: Дело в том что он должен дать первое вхождении и дальше, так как таких подстрок несколько, отличаются  они лишь тем, что находится между этими тремя буквами

Comment: @Izpodvorotni, исправил.

Comment: Выдает пустую строку, можете посоветовать что почитать по регуляркам

Comment: @Izpodvorotni, повнимательнее будьте. Регулярку то под свои буквы поправьте. Я символы взял другие просто.

Comment: Прошу прощения, мой косяк